# React Slick prev and next methods throw an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint-online, slick.js, spfx

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Birthday.module.scss';
import { IBirthdayProps } from './IBirthdayProps';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
import { initializeIcons } from '@uifabric/icons';
initializeIcons();

import Slider from 'react-slick';

export default class Birthday extends React.Component<IBirthdayProps, {}> {


  public next() {
    this.slider.slickNext();
  }
  public previous() {
    this.slider.slickPrev();
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IBirthdayProps> {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      rows: 2,
      slidesPerRow: 2,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed: 500,
      appendDots: dots => (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#ddd',
            padding: '5px',
            display: 'flex'
          }}
        >
          <ul style={{ margin: '0px', padding: '0px' }}> {dots} </ul>
        </div>
      )
    };
    return (
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
          <div className={styles.item}>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.item}>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.item}>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.item}>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.item}>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', padding: '30px', marginTop: '30px' }}>
          <Icon
            iconName="ChevronLeftSmall"
            className={styles.customArrow}
            onClick={this.next}
          />
          <Icon
            iconName="ChevronRightSmall"
            className={styles.customArrow}
            onClick={this.previous}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to make use of the react slick carousel.
I tried to customized it a bit so I created next and prev button which should trigger the carousel's method for next and previous.
To be clear I'm developing in SPFX, which is SharePoint framework, React with Typescript.
I get the following error as the code is written:(same for this.slider inside Slider Component)

[image]

I developed by the their docs here:
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods
I've tried creating variables as slide and slider and add them as props or as state or just a variable inside my class but it didn't succeed..

I expect the buttons to trigger the next and prev methods...

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReactSpFx.module.scss';
import { IReactSpFxProps } from './IReactSpFxProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, SPHttpClientConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

import Slider from "react-slick";
import "../../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
import "../../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { any } from 'prop-types';

export interface IReactItem{ 
  ID:string,
  Title:string,
  Address:string
}

export interface IReactGetItemsState{ 
  items:IReactItem[]
}

export default class ReactSpFx extends React.Component<IReactSpFxProps,IReactGetItemsState> {

  public constructor(props: IReactSpFxProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items:[]   
    };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);    
  }


  public componentDidMount() {
    var reactHandler = this;
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?select=ID,Title,Address`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1) .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
      response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {            
        reactHandler.setState({
          items: responseJSON.value
        });
      });  
    });   
  }

  protected slider;
  next() {
    this.slider.slickNext();
  }
  previous() {
    this.slider.slickPrev();
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactSpFxProps> {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div className={styles.reactSpFx}>
        <div className={styles.container}>  
        {(this.state.items || []).map(item => (
            <div key={item.ID} className={styles.row}>{item.Title}
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.Address.replace(/[\n\r]/g,"<br/>")}}></div> 
          </div> 
          ))}                          
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2> Single Item</h2>
          <Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
            <div>
              <h3>1</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>2</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>3</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>4</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>5</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>6</h3>
            </div>
          </Slider>
          <br/>
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.previous}>
            Previous
          </button>
          <button className="button" onClick={this.next}>
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    );    
  }
}
```

Suppose you mean IReactSpFxProps

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
export interface IReactSpFxProps {
  description: string,
  context: WebPartContext;
}
```

Comment: could you please share the interfaces also? @Lee_MSFT

Answer (score 7):

Using a functional component

````
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Slider from "react-slick";

const Homepage = () => {

  //creating the ref
  const customeSlider = React.creatRef();

  // setting slider configurations
  const [sliderSettings, setSliderSettings] = useState({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    arrows: false,
  })

  const gotoNext = () => {
    customeSlider.current.slickNext()
  }

  const gotoPrev = () => {
    customeSlider.current.slickPrev()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>gotoNext()}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={()=>gotoPrev()}>Previous</button>
      <Slider {...sliderSettings} ref={customeSlider}>
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Theree</div>
        <div>Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  )


}
export default Homepage```
````

Answer (score 1):

**Functional Base Component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
```

const ExampleComponent = () => {

must added

```
const [slider, setSlider] = useState<any>(null);
const next = () => {
    slider?.slickNext();
};
const previous = () => {
    slider?.slickPrev();
};
```

const settings = {
dots: false,
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 1,
}

```
return (
                <div>
                    <Slider {...settings} ref={(c: any) => setSlider(c)} >
                        {
                            example?.map((product: any) => (
                                <h key={example?.id}>example</h1>
                            ))
                        }
                    </Slider>
                </div>>
);
```

};
export default ExampleComponent ;

Answer (score 0):

you need to  define type for your `ref` that  needs to be a type of `HTMLDivElement` here how to do it:
in your class component add this:

```
private slider = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
```

Comment: did it now and got other error inside the methods:Property 'slickNext' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2339) @adel

Comment: Have you installed react-slick type its here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-slick

Answer (score 0):

For the functional-based components

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Slider from "react-slick";

const Homepage = () => {

  //creating the ref
  const customeSlider = useRef();

  // setting slider configurations
  var settings = {
dots: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 1,
initialSlide: 0,
arrows: false,
}

  const previous = () => {
    customeSlider.current.slickNext();
  };

  const next = () => {
    customeSlider.current.slickPrev();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={previous}>Previous</button>
      <Slider {...settings} ref={customeSlider}>
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Theree</div>
        <div>Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  )


}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Class-based components

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import Slider from "react-slick";

class Homepage extends Component {

 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.next=this.next.bind(this);
      this.previous=this.previous.bind(this)
 }
 next(){
      this.slider.slickNext();
 }
 previous(){
      this.slider.slickPrev();
 }

render() {
 // setting slider configurations
 var settings = {
dots: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 3000,
slidesToShow: 4,
slidesToScroll: 1,
initialSlide: 0,
arrows: false,
}


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={this.previous}>Previous</button>
      <Slider ref={c=>(this.slider=c)} {...settings}>
        <div>One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Theree</div>
        <div>Four</div>
        <div>Five</div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  )

}
}

export default Homepage;
```